# Nodejs freezes with MySQL large set of results feed into REDIS HMSET

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, redis

I have a script that executes 2 queries into MySQL with a SELECT, the resulting queries each produce one result set of 226,393 rows and the other 529,976. when fed into REDIS each row is added 4 times, one per unique data to store.

The first query seems to complete, no problem, yet the second query seems to freeze in the middle and stays there. I am fairly new into both NODEjs and REDIS and come from a traditional MySQL background.

Here is the code:

```
// Start the server
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log('Request received');

    for(var n = 0; n < qryArray.length; n++) {
        var qry = qryArray[n];

        // Send the query
        //console.log( n + ' :: ' + qry);
        connection.query(qry, function(err, rows, fields){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                console.log('Query response ' + rows.length + ' rows');
                //console.log(util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));

                errorCount = 0;
                goodCount  = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                    var row = rows[i];

                    j = 0;
                    //var fields = result.fields.map(function(f) { return f.name; })
                    fields.forEach(function(f){
                        if(f.name != 'latlng' && f.name != 'market' && f.name != 'technology'){
                            j++;

                            //console.log(('' + row[f.name]).toUpperCase() + '~' + i + '-' + j + '~' + row.latlng);
                            redisClient.hmset(('' + row[f.name]).toUpperCase() + '~' + i + '-' + j + '~' + row.latlng, row, function(error, result){
                                if(error){
                                    errorCount++;
                                    console.log(errorCount + ' ' + error + ' ' + f.name.toUpperCase() + ' : ' + ('' + row[f.name]).toUpperCase() + '~' + i + '-' + j + '~' + row.latlng + ' :: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
                                }else{
                                    goodCount++;
                                    console.log(goodCount);
                                    //console.log(goodCount + ' Redis stored: ' + f.name.toUpperCase() + ' : ' + ('' + row[f.name]).toUpperCase() + ' ' + result);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    });
                    //goodCount++;
                    //console.log(goodCount);
                }
                console.log('Finished indexing ' + rows.length + ' rows ' + goodCount);
            }
        });
    }
    console.log('Queries processed');

}).listen(port);
console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
```

Can someone please point me out as to what is wrong or how this can be improved for large data sets? Thanks!

After taking the pointer on adding the Async libraries for using a Queue, I modified the code but got in return a nasty Error:

> { [Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.] fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }

Here is the new code with the added functionality, please help:

```
// Initialize the queue
var q = async.queue(function(task){

    //console.log(('' + row[f.name]).toUpperCase() + '~' + i + '-' + j + '~' + row.latlng);
    redisClient.hmset(task.hk, task.r, function(error, result){
        if(error){
            errorCount++;
            console.log('Error: ' + errorCount);
            //console.log(errorCount + ' ' + error + ' ' + f.name.toUpperCase() + ' : ' + ('' + row[f.name]).toUpperCase() + '~' + i + '-' + j + '~' + row.latlng + ' :: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
        }else{
            goodCount++;
            console.log('Good: ' + goodCount);
            //console.log(goodCount + ' Redis stored: ' + f.name.toUpperCase() + ' : ' + ('' + row[f.name]).toUpperCase() + ' ' + result);
        }
    });

}, 50000);

// Assign callback for when all items in queue have been processed
q.drain = function(){
    console.log('All queue items have been processed ' + goodCount);
}

// Start the server
http.createServer( function( req, res ){
    console.log('Request received');

    for(var n = 0; n < qryArray.length; n++) {
        var qry = qryArray[n];

        // Send the query
        //console.log( n + ' :: ' + qry);
        connection.query(qry, function(err, rows, fields){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                console.log('Query response ' + rows.length + ' rows');
                //console.log(util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));

                errorCount = 0;
                goodCount  = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                    var row = rows[i];

                    var j = 0;
                    //var fields = result.fields.map(function(f) { return f.name; })
                    fields.forEach(function(f){
                        if(f.name != 'latlng' && f.name != 'market' && f.name != 'technology'){
                            j++;

                            var hkey = ('' + row[f.name]).toUpperCase() + '~' + i + '-' + j + '~' + row.latlng;
                            var task = {r: row, hk: hkey};
                            q.push(task, function(err){
                                if(err) console.log(err);
                            });
                        }
                    });

                }
                console.log('Finished indexing ' + rows.length + ' rows');
            }
        });
    }
    console.log('Queries processed');

}).listen(port);
console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
```

The error occured right after the 50K queue item completed successfully (the queue was initialized to 50k concurrent items).

I changed to MySQL pool mechanism for the disconnect issue, yet I still have the disconnects, please help. Also, it takes a ton of time before the actual inserts to REDIS start, is there something wrong there as well?

```
// Start the server
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();

    console.log('Request received');
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if(err){
            connection.release();
            return console.log('Database connection error ' + err);
        }
        console.log('Database is connected ' + connection.threadId + ' ...');

        for(var n = 0; n < qryArray.length; n++){
            var qry = qryArray[n];

            // Send the query
            connection.query(qry, function(err, rows, fields){
                connection.release();
                if(err){
                    return console.log('Query error: ' + err);
                }
                console.log('Query response ' + rows.length + ' rows');

                errorCount = 0;
                goodCount  = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                    var row = rows[i];

                    var j = 0;
                    fields.forEach(function(f){
                        if(f.name != 'latlng' && f.name != 'market' && f.name != 'technology'){
                            j++;

                            var hkey = ('' + row[f.name]).toUpperCase() + '~' + i + '-' + j + '~' + row.latlng;
                            var task = {r: row, hk: hkey};
                            q.push(task, function(err){
                                if(err) console.log(err);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                console.log('Finished indexing ' + rows.length + ' rows');
            });

            connection.on('error', function(err){
                return console.log('Database connection error ' + err);
            });
        }
        console.log('Queries processed');
    });

}).listen(port);
console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
```

Comment: What happens if you only execute the second query? Also, I'm assuming that the second query does not depend at all on the first query finishing first, correct?  Because you are running your queries concurrently, not consecutively.

Comment: According to the feedback I get from the console.log I only get as far as 1,059,952 (where the data to store is 529,976 x 4 = 2,119,904), so Im about in the middle and then nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Most likely Redis is stalled since you are making almost  226,393*4 + 529,976 * 4 concurrent requests from a single client.

Comment: Thank you everyone, can you please point me out as to how to solve this?

Comment: You can try running the queries in chunks. Try this library: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: @hassansin Good point.  At over 3 million hashes it looks like you're trying to use about 600MB of memory according to the Redis FAQ (http://redis.io/topics/faq)

Comment: I ran the script with only the sencond query and got the exact same result, I got as far as 1,059,952.

Comment: Thank you for the response! :D I see where this can solve the issue. Just one more thing, would it be too much to ask if you could maybe write some code as to how I could add this? Since I'm a newbie it takes me more time to digest this. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this regarding Redis disconnects. https://www.exratione.com/2013/01/nodejs-connections-will-end-close-and-otherwise-blow-up/  Not really sure this is the answer but it is worth knowing.

Comment: I added the new code and my question, among other things, is why does it take so long for the Queue to start doing the processing? It does tak over 3min maybe even more. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: @ Francisco  I don't know, but keep in mind that the strength of Node is in its ability to deal with many concurrent requests and handling i/o asynchronously, not in dealing with CPU-intensive tasks.  Is this a task that will run often, or are you just trying to populate a database one time?

Comment: @HeadCode I was given the assignment to adapt the script from the original Postgress to MySQL, I do not know if this will be a one timer or more will be needed to use as part of an automated process. Learned Nodejs, or more precisely, have just started to learn Nodejs on the go to get this done one week ago.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping me out, the script now works using MySQL Pooling, Job Queues and I added the HTTP Dispatcher for a simple status report on the progress of the main task: inserting MySQL data set results into REDIS. It took several hours to complete (+3million inserts).

I'm posting the resulting script in hopes that it can be both improved and can also help enlighten others in similar situation.

```
// MySQL initialization
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'gta_ro',
    password : 'glacier',
    database : 'tower'
});

// Async Queue initialization
var insertCount = 0;
var q = async.queue(function(task, callback){

    redisClient.hmset(task.hk, task.r, function(error, result){
        if(error){
            errorCount++;
            console.log('Error: ' + errorCount);
            //console.log(errorCount + ' ' + error + ' ' + f.name.toUpperCase() + ' : ' + ('' + row[f.name]).toUpperCase() + '~' + i + '-' + j + '~' +     row.latlng + ' :: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
        }else{
            goodCount++;
            console.log('Good: ' + goodCount);
            //console.log(goodCount + ' Redis stored: ' + f.name.toUpperCase() + ' : ' + ('' + row[f.name]).toUpperCase() + ' ' + result);
        }
    });
    return setImmediate(function() { callback() });
}, 1000);

// Async Queue Empty callback (triggered after last item has been consumed)
q.drain = function(){
    console.log('All queue items have been processed ' + goodCount);
}

// Start the server
httpStarted = false;
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    dispatcher.dispatch(req, res);

    if(!httpStarted){
        httpStarted = true;

        console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
            if(err){
                connection.release();
                return console.log('Database connection error ' + err);
            }
            console.log('Database is connected ' + connection.threadId + ' ...');

            for(var n = 0; n < qryArray.length; n++){
                var qry = qryArray[n];

                // Send the query
                connection.query(qry, function(err, rows, fields){
                    if(err){
                        return console.log('Query error: ' + err);
                    }

                    //connection.release();
                    console.log('Query response ' + rows.length + ' rows');

                    errorCount = 0;
                    goodCount  = 0;
                    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                        var row = rows[i];

                        var j = 0;
                        fields.forEach(function(f){
                            if(f.name != 'latlng' && f.name != 'market' && f.name != 'technology'){
                                j++;

                                q.push({r: row, hk: ('' + row[f.name]).toUpperCase() + '~' + i + '-' + j + '~' + row.latlng}, function(err){
                                    if(err) console.log(err);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    console.log('Finished indexing');
                });

                connection.on('error', function(err){
                    return console.log('Database connection error ' + err);
                });
            }
            console.log('Queries processed');
        });
    }
}).listen(port);

dispatcher.onGet('/', function(req, res){
    if(httpStarted){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('MySQL Indexer running' + '\n');

        console.log('MySQL Indexer running');
    }
});

dispatcher.onGet('/status', function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('Status ' + q.length() + '\n');

    console.log('Status ' + q.length());
});
```

A couple of additions would be to add a kill/link to kill the process and improve the status reporting, to name a few.